# Textbox to a cell in hidden sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to make a macro for userform to input data in to hiden sheet.  I have tryied application screening then visible the sheet and then input the data in a specific cell but ints not working like that. 
Anyone know how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to make a sheet visible to populate it.

For example, create a new workbook and make sure there is a sheet in there called Sheet2

Hide Sheet2

Put this into the debug window (ctrl-g) in the VB Editor

```
Sheets("Sheet2").range("A1").Formula = "Text in a hidden sheet"
```

press enter

Unhide Sheet2 and look at cell A1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like thats not the only problem i have got. I will try to explain it.  When a press a button a userform pop up and there is a text box in it. You write a name in the box, click a button and the name appears is a cell in one of the sheets that is hidden. That we already did. 
Then i want to move to another sub which is located in one of the sheets. The other sub is for printing out a hidden sheet.

I have an Option Explicit there and 
A sub called PrintFile.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheets("Opis")
.Visible = True
.PrintOut
.Visible = False
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

The problem is that it's giving me an error and i can't switch to the other sub.
Where im doing it wrong?

Comment: What is the error it gives you? I just created a workbook and tried this and it works: Sheets("Sheet2").printout

Comment: After Sheets("Sheet2").range("A1").Formula = "Text in a hidden sheet". Im writing PrintFile to call the other sub and its giving me sub or function not defined

Comment: I also tried new workbook, add button, when clicked userform with one button appear. When button bis clicked switch to sub on sheet but i get the same answer. Im not sure how to define the sub so sheet is printed. Object?

Comment: I fix it. Stored the print sub in modul and that do the trick. Silly me :) Thank you for your time. Really appreciate that.